# How do you programatically get a list of a computer's recording devices?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to get a list of a computers recording devices programatically and then change the default, I have managed to do this with playback devices in the below code, however I would like to do this with recording devices.

This is the list of devices that the below code returns:

[image: This is the list of devices that the below code returns]

These are the devices that I want to see and change:

[image: These are the devices that I want to see and change]

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MMDeviceEnumerator DevEnum = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
        MMDeviceCollection devices = DevEnum.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(EDataFlow.eRender, EDeviceState.DEVICE_STATE_ACTIVE);
        MMDevice DefaultDevice = DevEnum.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eRender, ERole.eMultimedia);
        MMDevice SecondaryDevice = null;
        PolicyConfigClient client = new PolicyConfigClient();

        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("List of devices");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
        for (int i = 1; i < devices.Count; i++)
        { 
            if (devices[i].ID != DefaultDevice.ID)
            {
                SecondaryDevice = devices[i];
            }
            Console.WriteLine(devices[i].FriendlyName);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Default Device");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine(DefaultDevice.FriendlyName);
        Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Secondary Device");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine(SecondaryDevice.FriendlyName);
        Console.ReadLine();


        client.SetDefaultEndpoint(SecondaryDevice.ID, ERole.eCommunications);
        client.SetDefaultEndpoint(SecondaryDevice.ID, ERole.eMultimedia);
        client.SetDefaultEndpoint(SecondaryDevice.ID, ERole.eConsole);

        DefaultDevice = DevEnum.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eRender, ERole.eMultimedia);

        Console.WriteLine("New Default Device");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine(DefaultDevice.FriendlyName);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `EDataFlow.eCapture` instead of `EDataFlow.eRender`

Comment: That has worked, thank you

Comment: The way you can do this depends on what API you're intended to follow. Let say, WPF would be differ from UWP, as well as Net Core. Could you specify your target NET framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do this is as Chetan Ranpariya mentioned in the comment and is to use EDataFlow.eCapture instead of EDataFlow.eRender below is the revised working code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MMDeviceEnumerator DevEnum = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
        MMDeviceCollection devices = DevEnum.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(EDataFlow.eCapture, EDeviceState.DEVICE_STATE_ACTIVE);
        MMDevice DefaultDevice = DevEnum.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eCapture, ERole.eMultimedia);
        MMDevice SecondaryDevice = null;
        PolicyConfigClient client = new PolicyConfigClient();

        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("List of sound cards installed");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
        for (int i = 0; i < devices.Count; i++)
        { 
            if (devices[i].ID != DefaultDevice.ID)
            {
                SecondaryDevice = devices[i];
            }
            Console.WriteLine(devices[i].FriendlyName);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Default Device");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine(DefaultDevice.FriendlyName);
        Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Secondary Device");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine(SecondaryDevice.FriendlyName);
        Console.ReadLine();


        client.SetDefaultEndpoint(SecondaryDevice.ID, ERole.eCommunications);
        client.SetDefaultEndpoint(SecondaryDevice.ID, ERole.eMultimedia);
        client.SetDefaultEndpoint(SecondaryDevice.ID, ERole.eConsole);

        DefaultDevice = DevEnum.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eCapture, ERole.eMultimedia);

        Console.WriteLine("New Default Device");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine(DefaultDevice.FriendlyName);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```